# How to get back a hidden part of the mesh when Alt+H is not working?

Tags: objects, visibility

I was (am) working on a mesh. I selected part of it, hid it, moded the other part, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and nothing, go into object mode it shows the entire mesh (object) go into edit, I cannot get it to reshow everything again.

[image]

Comment: Could you specify which part of the face is missing? I used Alt+H in Edit Mode and got the same mesh as in Object Mode.

Comment: @lemon It could quite possibly be that the OS or, if in a *nix type OS, the window manager grabs the `Alt+H`. I have that problem with WindowMaker.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley, no... in fact, (I have removed my comment, but I was wrong). Just go in edit mode, and alt+H

Comment: @metaphor_set  yeah I just figured it out, I had reInstalled i3 wm today and finished setting it up, and now am using i3 WM. then I figured out why it didn't work is because my Alt Key is a mod key in i3 WM it is over ridding that key. thanks ..

Comment: @lemon read comment above thanks for you help

Comment: No prob. At least we've learned about the importance of detailed information - once again ;-)

Comment: it was a thinking out side of the box (belender) experience for sure. @metaphor_set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in Edit mode, Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or in the menu bar select *Mesh> Show/Hide> Show Hidden*

[image]

Comment: yeah I figured it out, then figured out somemore. I just changed back to i3 WM. a few hours ago, I was using xfce4. I'd just found what you're showing me now by looking around, then wondered why is not my alt+h working now? then hid someting again, then hit alt+H then realized oh yeah, my ALT Key is a mod key in i3 WM so i3 is over riding it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cegaton Considering the question is about how to do if Alt+H isn't working, is it really a good idea to include Alt+H as a possible solution?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was Simple Sticky Notes App that overwrote the key binding. 
I've opened Simple Sticky Notes App Settings, removed all key bindings and all works in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you accidentally switched language settings to English UK in windows, this often happens with multiple loop select, shift alt and pressing the wrong [windows] key. Switching back to English US keyboard will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well, googled for at least 20 minutes until I realized that I was in User Perspective (Local). Leaving this here for any other starters struggling with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

It was the *Perspective* view <kbd>/</kbd> that fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, although I initially thought <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> wasn't working, in reality it was the perspective from which I was viewing the object that was causing the problem. Be sure to rotate around the object to be sure you're not missing anything.

Comment: This is hardly a new answer, it's just a comment on an already accepted given answer with an additional hint.